# PHP MySQL fetch_assoc prints "0" at the end

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello after a while fetch_assoc loop PHP prints "0" at the end.

my code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("***********","***********","************","********");

    if($conn->connect_errno){
        printf("Connection failed!", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    } else {
        $result = $conn->query("select * from VoiceJoin order by VoiceJoinID desc limit 5");
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['UserName']." ";
    }

    $conn->close();

}
```

I also tried it with:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['UserName']." ";
        }

    }
```

doesn't work.
[output (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTpbP.png)

Thanks!

code from my php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class getLatestVoiceJoin extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'get:latest:voice:join';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Get the 5 latest VoiceJoin';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("*","*","*","*");

    if($conn->connect_errno){
        printf("Connection failed!", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    } else {
        $result = $conn->query("select * from VoiceJoin order by VoiceJoinID desc limit 5");
    }


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['UserName']."-";
    }

    $conn->close();

}
}
```

Comment: Have you shown us ALL the code in that script?

Comment: Indeed there is nothing in the current code that can cause that zero in the image.. Unless the 0 is within the table as a username

Comment: if this is all of the relevant code, the `0` has to be the `UserName` :D @RaymondNijland - maybe you inserted an empty one and default value is `0`?

Comment: This is a command that I made with Laravel. There is one more function but this function only constructs the command. And in the username is no zero: http://prntscr.com/jyj763

Comment: @Pilan, I thought the same thing, but the output seems to show 6 items instead of 5.

Comment: @Trexon, can you change `." "` to `."-"` and re-run your code so we can see if there happens to be a space in one of the user names?

Comment: sure: http://prntscr.com/jyj89k

Comment: ah you right, missed the limit 5 - buuut what if one name consists of actually 2 with a space inbetween? :D - ok unlikely - we need more code plz

Comment: It seems the "0" comes from the Laravel PHP framework. Because I also can run the command in the console and in the console there is no "0". :/ http://prntscr.com/jyj93z

Comment: yeah since there is no `-` at the end. the output is **not** coming from `echo $row...` - as i said **more code plz**

Comment: does anyone know Laravel? ^^

Comment: before you blame the framework, please give more code :)

Comment: added the hole file^^

Comment: Laravel GitHub Project: https://github.com/laravel/laravel ;D

Comment: since you are getting no `0` at the commandline, my next guesss would be its in the template

Comment: Thats my template: http://prntscr.com/jyjlzl at the @section the other php file adds stuff and here im calling the command: http://prntscr.com/jyjm8n